# Assigning Process IDs to a variable in a shell script

Tags: shell, unix, grep

I want to assign all process ids to a variable.
For example the result for
pgrep abc

1. 29845
2. 29846

I want to assign these 2 ids to  a variable like this
a = '29845 29845'.

The variable a should contain the 2 process ids separated by a space.
The whole purpose of this is to kill all the process ids

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some like this

```
cat file
29845
29846

var=$(awk '{printf "%s ",$1}' t)
echo $var
29845 29846
```

You may skip `grep` and only use `awk`

Answer (score 0):

I tested the commands by starting `sleep 320 &` three times.

You can assign the output of a command like this:

```
procs=$(pgrep sleep | tr '\n' ' ')
```

When you want to kill the processen, consider

```
pgrep sleep | xargs kill -9
```

or

```
pkill sleep
```